# Передача функции в функцию в javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Есть такой пример в javascript:

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grapes', 'pear', 'passionfruit'];

// The three values on the callback function are:
// element - The element being traversed
// index - The current index of the item in the array starting at 0
// array - The array being traversed (probably mostly irrelevant)

fruits.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
   console.log(index, element); 
});
```

в метод `forEach` передается функция. Я так понимаю, что в методе `forEach` где-то эта передаваемая функция вызывается. Чтобы ее вызвать, нужно ей передать 3 аргумента (желательно). Люди, написавшие код этой функции как-то там перебирают элементы массива `fruits` и вызывают мою `callback` функцию, передавая ей все эти три параметра. Каким образом они знают что на каком месте стоит? Ведь по сути я могу написать не

```
function(element, index,array)
```

а

```
function(myelement, myindex,myarray)
```

т.е. название параметров сменить и все равно будет работать. Получается, что элементы, передаваемые в функцию "привязаны" к месту параметра - 1, 2, 3 по счету. Так? Или где-то я ошибаюсь. Подскажите, пожалуйста?

Вынесу вопрос отдельно:

параметры, передаваемые в колбэк функцию "привязаны" к месту параметра?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Аргументы, переданные в функцию - это, по сути, массив `arguments[]`. Ваше предположение, что порядок имеет значение, верно.

[Магия JavaScript: arguments](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117868/) (Хабр).

Comment: строго говоря, arguments - не массив

Comment: @mymedia напишете ответ про это?

Answer (score 7):

> Люди, написавшие код этой функции как-то там перебирают элементы массива fruits и вызывают мою callback функцию, передавая ей все эти три параметра. Каким образом они знают что на каком месте стоит?

Все очень просто - они не знают как описана функция, которая передается в качестве коллбэка.

Они просто берут ее и вызывают передавая ей параметры: element, index, sourse_array.

Кроме этого, у коллбэка может быть указан контекст (значение *this*) внутри функции.

Так как разработчики *forEach* не знают, какую функцию им передадут, они просто вызывают любой коллбэк в следующем виде

```
callback(element,index,sourse_array)
```

Либо дополнительно устанавливая *this*, что эквивалентно вызову [*call*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
callback.call(thisArg,element,index,sourse_array)
```

При этом сама функция коллбэка может быть объявлена с тремя параметрами, с двумя, с четырьмя, вообще без параметров и т.д.

Подробнее описание [forEach в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 6):

Вы аргументы можете назвать как угодно, например

```
fruits.forEach(function(first, second, third) {
   // first всегда будет итерируемым елементом масива
   // second всегда будет его номером
   // third всегда будет масивом по которому осуществляется итерация
   // например даст true
   console.log(third[second] === first) 
});
```

Кроме того, все аргументы являются необязательными (хотя forEach без первого елемента теряет смысл)

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Там же в конце есть пример реализации функции `forEach()`

Comment: Спасибо! В реализации написан как раз такой подход.