# Как написать функцию, которая после передается в filter и выдает определенный отрезок из массива?

Tags: javascript

Немного не понял задачу, которая выглядит так:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const result = arr.filter(getBetween(2, 5));


console.log("result: ", result); // [3, 4]
```

я так понял нужно написать функцию которая принимает в себя два параметра и после выдает нужный массив.

Comment: неясны правила для выбора элементов

Comment: Да вот я тоже не понял чего от меня хотят, на этом вопросе и завалился.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо такое

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const result = arr.filter(getBetween(2, 5));
console.log("result: ", result); // [3, 4]

function getBetween(min, max){
   return ( value => (value > min) && (value < max) );
}
```

В данной задаче `getBetween` должно возвращать функцию сравнения, которая будет использована для фильтрации. Запись `.. => ..` это краткое определение анонимной функции. То есть `x => y` эквивалентно

```
function (x) { return y; }
```

Применительно к данному сниппету вернем функцию для фильтрации:

```
return function (value){
           return (value > min) && (value > max)
       };
```

При этом передачу внутрь аргументов min/max называют "замыканием" функции на внешнюю область видимости.

в целом весь алгоритм будет представлять из себя примерно такую итоговую последовательность шагов:

```
let filterFunction = getBetween(2,5); // 2 -> min, 5 -> max
let result = [];
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let check = filterFunction(arr[i]);  // arr[i] -> value
    if (check) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
    }  
}
```

Comment: А где можно более подробно прочитать об использовании value внутри метода? Есть ли ещё какие-либо  "магические" переменные?

Comment: сразу несколько случаев в которых непонятно что делать, начиная с вызова `getBetween(5, 2)` и заканчивая разыми данными. Неизвестно упорядочен ли массив. Но конкретно для примера в вопросе сработает, да

Comment: @XelaNimed `value` - это НЕ магическая переменная - это просто имя аргумента функции, оно может быть любым допустимым идентификатором

Comment: @XelaNimed несколько дополнил ответ

Comment: @teran теперь понятно, спасибо.

Comment: @XelaNimed да, подробнее тут: [Передача функции в функцию в javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573789/186999) пример для `forEach` - но суть та же